# How to link 2 buttons to 2 different html links in eclpse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have created 2 buttons and i want to link both of them to 2 different html links,but i could link only one by using this below code....

package com.kk24.adding two buttons;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://........."));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
             }
        });

}
```

Now i want to link button 2 to another link how do we link ????

Give me step by step details if there is something to import or creating a class or so.....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You clearly just copied code you don't understand and are asking someone to write the code for you. That is not what *StackOverflow* is for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://link1."));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
             }
        });

Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink2.setData(Uri.parse("http://link2."));
                    startActivity(myWebLink2);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

create new `String stringUris` then make the `String stringUris` equals the first link in the first button and in the second button equals the second link then start the activity

```
    String stringUris;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringUris = "http://www.example1.com";
                Intent Intent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse(stringUris));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
             }
        });

Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stringUris = "http://www.example2.com";
                Intent Intent2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink2.setData(Uri.parse(stringUris));
                    startActivity(myWebLink2);

             }
```

you can use a class for showing webview within the app if you want the class contact me.

Answer (score 0):

On xml file in each button add two attributes `android:tag` with the url and  `android:onClick` with the method name that handle the event

```
<Button android:id="@id/btSite1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="http://site_1.com" 
    android:onClick="openBrowser"/>

<Button android:id="@id/btSite2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="http://site_2.com"
    android:onClick="openBrowser"/>
```

On activity declare the method openBrowser to handle the click event:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void openBrowser(View view){

        //Get url from tag
        String url = (String)view.getTag();
        if(url != null){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

            //pass the url to intent data
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when an button is clicked the openBrowser method is called and the browser is open.